# When i have not config repository in pom.xml,the mirror is not working

Tags: maven

settings.xml:

```
 <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>d:/maven/repository2</localRepository>
<mirrors>

<mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <name>internal nexus repository</name>
        <url>http://mynexus/repo/public/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
 </mirrors>

 </settings>
```

pom.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytest</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>test-base</module>
       
    </modules>
  
</project>
```

The test-boot pom.xml was upload to mirror server.

When my local repository hasn't the test-boot pom.xml,run command :
mvn clean -X

```html
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from D:\Users\mypath\maven\settings4.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from D:\Users\mypath\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at d:\maven\repository2
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for d:\maven\repository2
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.test:test-boot:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (d:\maven\repository2)
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.ms:mytest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 13
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.ms:mytest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 13

 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
 at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
 at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
 at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.test.ms:mytest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (D:\Users\mypath\Desktop\test32\mytest\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.test.ms:mytest:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 13 -> [Help 2]
org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:197)
 at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:246)
 at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1000)
 at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:800)
 at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:329)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:469)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:438)
 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:401)
 at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
 at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
 at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
 at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
 at org.apache.maven.project.ProjectModelResolver.resolveModel(ProjectModelResolver.java:193)
 ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
 ... 30 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

We can see maven use the local repository,but not use remote repository ,so the mirror is not working.
When I add repository to the pom.xml.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-boot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.test.ms</groupId>
    <artifactId>mytest</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>test-base</module>
       
    </modules>
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>test</id>
            <url>http://10.2.2.2:222</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
  
</project>
```

Maven will use the remote repository and the mirror is working.

```html
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\Users\mypath\mytest "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52882:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.1.2 -s D:\Users\mypath\settings4.xml clean -X -f pom.xml
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\jre
Default locale: zh_CN, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
......
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from D:\Users\mypath\settings4.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\conf\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from D:\Users\mypath\.m2\toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at d:\maven\repository2
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for d:\maven\repository2
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Using mirror nexus (http://mynexus/repo/public/) for test (http://10.2.2.2:222).
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.test:test-boot:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (d:\maven\repository2)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for com.test:test-boot:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Using mirror nexus (http://mynexus/repo/public/) for central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).
[DEBUG] Extension realms for projectcom.test.ms:mytest:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Using mirror nexus (http://mynexus/repo/public/) for sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Using mirror nexus (http://mynexus/repo/public/) for apache.snapshots (http://repository.apache.org/snapshots).
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.test:test-boot:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.9.RELEASE: (none)
  .......
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] mytest ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.214 s]
[INFO] mytest-base ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.417 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-05-15T09:53:23+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 37M/238M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If I don't add the repository in the pom and my local repository is empty.How can I configura maven make the mirror effective?

Comment: it looks like nobody has deployed it to your local repository...

Comment: yes,local repository has not deployed,but maven only use local repo to find the package,why it don't access remote repo , e.g.:central.